# problem with z-index of an empty div layer in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, z-index

I have a problem with z-index in IE8 (other IS not tested yet):

The following JS creates some html/css:

```
document.write('<img id="' + sas_Banderole.getObjId('cb') + '" src="' + cburl + '" style="position:absolute; top:5px; cursor:pointer;" onclick="sas_Banderole.trigger();" border=0>');
document.write('<div ID="closeReminder" style="z-index:10000; background-color:transparent; text-align: right; display:none; width:30px; height:100px; right: 0px; position:absolute; top:5px; cursor:pointer; color:fff; font-size:10px;" onclick="reminder_close();" border=0>&nbsp;</div>');


document.write('</div>');
```

Result should be, that I have:

- an IMG tag (close button) with a
  closing function.
- a DIV tag, which
  creates an div layer "CloseReminder"
  with an high z-index and an onClick
  event for closing an parent layer

The DIV must be in front of the IMG and should accoring to the css.

In FF, CHrome, Opera etc. it is working but in IE8 the layer is laying BEHIND the image. I can´t understand, why...

I found out, that if I give the layer a background-color (f.e. blue), the div is laying in front of the image, unfortunetaly not, if I give it the background-color "transparent" (it has to be unvisible)

Has someone a clue?
Thanks for helping me,

Best,
Dirk

Comment: why don't you put the onclick on the image btw?

Answer (score 5):

A workaround:

Try adding  `background: black; filter: alpha(opacity=0);` to the `#closeReminder` div. Not nice, but at least it works...

I guess there was some nicer solution, but I can't remember it (so it might just be a drunken dream).

Comment: Thanks, that worked:


 document.write('<div ID="closeReminder" style="  text-align: right; display:none; width:30px; height:100px; right: 0px; position:absolute; top:5px; color:white; font-size:10px; cursor:pointer; filter: alpha(opacity=0);" onclick="reminder_close();"></div>');
 if (sas_IsIE==1) { document.getElementById("closeReminder").style.backgroundColor="yellow"; }

dirty, but I didn´t found another way. 

Cheers,
Dirk