# Turn a collection of headings, paragraphs and lists into one hyperlink

Tags: html, hyperlink

Is there a valid non js way to turn a collection of headings, paragraphs and lists into one url? (like in advertisements?)

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="allclickable">
      <h2>Fresh Bread</h2>
      <p>Delivered to your door</p>
      <ul>
          <li>Daily</li>
          <li>Fresh</li>
          <li>Bread</li>
      </ul>
</a>
```

This does not validate and I do want the href to be display as block element (so also the space around the text is clickable).

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a less ugly way to do this but:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<h2>Fresh Bread</h2>
...
<a class="allclickable" href="http://www.example.com"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper { position: relative; }
.allclickable { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
```

Basically you just pust the link over the stuff. Only downside is that the text underneath is unselectable. But it's valid :).

Of course you will have a problem with IE, see solution here: [problem with z-index of an empty div layer in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545002/problem-with-z-index-of-an-empty-div-layer-in-ie8/4545548#4545548)

Comment: You also need to add 'width: 100%; height: 100%;'

Comment: Nope. Link will be stretched to the parent size.

Comment: Cool, I guess this is the answer for me as I won't need the text to be selectable.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't see the right and bottom declaration. There is however a small typo. 'right; 0' should be 'right: 0'

Answer (score 1):

Use html5. In html5 this is allowed.

But be aware that some browsers will generate a different DOM where they will remove the link and place it inside every block element. So

```
<a><h3>header</h3><p>para</p></a>
```

will become

```
<h3><a>header</a></h3><p><a>para</a></p>.
```

Not that big of a deal, but it might mess up some CSS selectors.

Comment: Yes, when I inspected the DOM this is what made me realize something was acting strangely. But good to know it's valid HTML5